# Trying IntelliJ with spring 3.0 MVC, how to import required libs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I'm trying out intelliJ's commercial editor with spring mvc 3.0

It seemed to have imported the files into the lib, but I guess I am missing something.
I have downloaded spring 3.0 in my downloads folder, but I haven't imported them into the editor since it set things up for me automatically.

The annotation:
`@RequestMapping` is not being picked up, so I guess the required libraries are not there.

Trying to import these libraries doesn't seem to work, how to I import my fresh set of spring .jar's ?

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust your module dependencies to include the downloaded jars.

Comment: file-->project structure. select modules, under project settings, on left hand side, select dependencies, add...

(using version 8)

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to set up as a maven project. This is not an answer but just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

See: [Help need to get Spring MVC project going with IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119280/help-need-to-get-spring-mvc-going-with-intellij)